# ¿Por qué falla la validación "valor IsNot Nothing And valor.Equals(x)"?

Tags: vb.net

Estoy dándole mantenimiento a un sistema en Visual Basic. Nunca he trabajado con ese lenguaje, pero tengo experiencia en C#, así que creo no estar del todo perdido.

Lo que si me tomo por sorpresa fue que no podía usar la siguiente validación (ejemplo):

```
Dim valor As String = Nothing

If valor IsNot Nothing And valor.Equals("hola") Then
    'Hacer algo...
End If
```

Porque si lo hago, me lanza una `System.NullReferenceException`.

Ahora bien, sí reescribo la condición de esta forma, no tendré ningún problema:

```
Dim valor As String = Nothing

If valor IsNot Nothing Then
    If valor.Equals("hola") Then
        'Hacer algo
    End If
End If
```

Sin embargo, si quisiera saber porque falla solo en el primer escenario si en C# no he tenido un problema en validaciones como esa. He buscado un poco en internet, pero parece que no doy con los términos correctos porque no he encontrado ninguna respuesta.

Comment: vos que tenes abierto vb.net lo vas a poder probar... se llama short circuit.. y viene por [aca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8409488/73749)

Comment: @gbianchi ¡Gracias! No conocía ese concepto para nada a pesar de que lo usaba sin darme cuenta jaja.